# Raspberry Pi and OpenCV. The cv2.error while capture the image through camera lens

Tags: python, pi-4, opencv, picamera

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43572387/error-215-size-width0-size-height0-occurred-when-attempting-to-display-a

I have the similar issue with this discussion, after I read it still don't have clue for how to address mine,that I post my case here

```
joy@raspberrypi:~ $ hostnamectl
   Static hostname: raspberrypi
         Icon name: computer
        Machine ID: 4aa79d3da798421f9882083733d765d5
           Boot ID: b42eea511b8d4ad5bfec964bfb792d1b
  Operating System: Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
            Kernel: Linux 5.15.61-v8+
      Architecture: arm64
```

*I use Raspberry Pi 4 ; 32 bit, linux Linux 5.15.61-v8+ run python3 ;  logitech USB camera lens ; run in virtual environment*

- the python script `opencv_camera.py`

```
import cv2
 
# define a video capture object
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(1) ########## 1- device id =1###if 1 deosn't work try 2
 
while(True):
     
    ret, frame = vid.read()
 
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
     
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
 
vid.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

error occur:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) .... in function 'imshow'
```

- the output:

```
(venv) joy@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ python opencv_camera.py
[ WARN:0@0.020] global /tmp/pip-wheel-u79916uk/opencv-python_ea2489746b3a43bfb3f2b5331b7ab47a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (902) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video1): can't open camera by index
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joy/Desktop/opencv_camera.py", line 14, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) /tmp/pip-wheel-u79916uk/opencv-python_ea2489746b3a43bfb3f2b5331b7ab47a/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:967: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'
```

Comment: This "question" like your previous lacks any information. What OS? You haven't said what YOU did or what you are attempting to do. You haven't actually asked a question, merely claimed you have a similar issue to someone else years ago on a different platform.

Comment: thanks for advice, my OS is Linux 5.15.61-v8+ , I tried to solved my issue by read other people discussion, but I'm stock on using there solution address on mine. And my main question, is want to solve `cv2.error:` in function `imshow`. Sorry, I though I made myself clear enough, but still have more things to learn

Comment: `Linux 5.15.61-v8+` is a kernel NOT an OS, but from the edited question it appears you are probably running Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye 64bit, which contradicts your Question. Unless you explain what you installed and how no one can help. Why are you running a virtual environment - this is an advanced technique but you seem to be struggling with basics?

Comment: i just start for about 2 weeks, always  thanks  for ur advicing